# kotlin Importing sign and floordiv in intellij

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

This is probably a dumb question, but I'm struggling to use sign and floordiv, and I'm assuming its an importation issue.

I was trying to implement a function to get rounded up division. (I found the function on SE)
One error says `Kotlin: Unresolved reference: floorDiv` and the other`Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Double was expected`

I checked kotlinlang.org, floordiv seems to be in the standard library `https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/floor-div.html`

and for sign, kotlinlang says it works for Int `val Int.sign: Int`, as well as the error on play.kotlinlang.org

> Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: public val Double.sign: Double defined in kotlin.math public val Float.sign: Float defined in kotlin.math public val Int.sign: Int defined in kotlin.math public val Long.sign: Int defined in kotlin.math

I imported sign with `import kotlin.math.sign`

I know I'm probably missing something dumb, but I can't figure it out, and I can't find anything online as to what the issue might be.

EDIT:

the code that is throwing the error is

`var result = dividend / divisor + sign(dividend % divisor)`

or

> fun Int.ceilDiv(other: Int): Int {
> return this.floorDiv(other) + this.rem(other).sign.absoluteValue }

I tried bringing it out of the function to try and debug, also changed it a bit so I could read it clearer. Both throw errors.

EDIT2:
If the above code snippets don't count as Minimum Reproducable Example, I copied this from where I tried in KotlinLang:

```
import kotlin.math.sign

fun main() {
    for(dividend in 1..10){
        for(divisor in 1..5){
            var rem = dividend % divisor
            var result = dividend / divisor + sign(rem)
            print(result)
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried both sign(rem) and Int.sign(rem), the error is `Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Double was expected`

Comment: So what is the code that you have these problems with?

Comment: var result = dividend / divisor + sign(dividend % divisor)

Comment: What I posted in the edit doesn't count?
either way, Here is what I put into kotlinlang, and it doesn't work:

import kotlin.math.sign
import kotlin.UByte

fun main() {
    for(dividend in 1..10){
        for(divisor in 1..5){
            var rem = dividend % divisor
            var result = dividend / divisor + Int.sign(rem)
            print(result)
        }
    }
}

Comment: By the way, what's the problem with `floorDiv`? The `ceilDiv` function in the question compiles. It also shows that you *do* know how to use `sign` correctly.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with floorDiv. IntelliJ is returning `Kotlin: Unresolved reference: floorDiv`  and not compiling floorDiv. kotlinlang is throwing `Unresolved reference: floorDiv`. (the line of code that is throwing is     `print(1.floorDiv(3));`
) -----------------                   for sign, I guess I got turned around. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions and properties that are declared like these:

```
fun Int.floorDiv(other: Int)
val Int.sign: Int
```

where there is a type name and a dot before the name of the function/property, are [*extensions*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html).

Instead of calling them like this:

```
floorDiv(a, b)
sign(x)
```

You should use them like this:

```
a.floorDiv(b)
x.sign
```